# NSCollectionView not releasing memory of Collection View Item prototype under ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, core-animation, nscollectionview

I am using an `NSCollectionView` to display the results of a database query (using an array controller).

Every time I do a search, a large amount of memory is used on the `NSCollectionViewItem` prototype view and is never released after moving past the view that contains the `NSCollectionView`.

The collection view prototype is an custom subclass of `NSBox` (uses `drawRect:` to visually modify the box). The `NSBox` contains several `NSTextFieldCells`. For each search I do (20+ records returned) about 100 MB is used on my custom `NSBox` class (`CALayer`) and never released.

If I remove the custom class from the `NSBox` prototype the memory is no longer used, however with or without the `NSBox` subclass, `NSTextFieldCell` (no custom subclass used) will use 50MB for every large search I do which never gets released.

How can I ensure the memory taken by the components of the collection view items gets released once I load a new view?

Comment: Yes this is an ARC application.

Comment: I am beginning to narrow this issue down.  It is related to enabling core animation on a view.  Before, I was enabling core animation on the content view of the main window.  I now only enable it on one specific view.  The problem persists on that specific view.  Every time that view with the CA layer enabled is created, it claims additional memory and is never released once the view is removed from the superview.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough detail to give a concrete answer. At the very least, you'd need to post the code related to managing the view that you've determined is causing the memory usage. My recommendation is to use Instruments to profile the app and determine exactly what's using the memory. Then, see if there's something that you're not releasing. With ARC, you don't call release, but it's certainly possible to inadvertently keep a strong reference to some object, or to create a retain cycle between two objects, causing it/them to never be released.